# MotionLayout progress jumps from 0 to 1 without intermediate steps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I have a MotionLayout with a TransitionListener and progress seems to go from 0 to 1 for my MotionScene:

```xml
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/header_expanded"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/header_condensed"
        app:duration="2000">

        <OnSwipe
             app:touchAnchorId="@id/view_pager"
            app:dragDirection="dragDown"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"/>

        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation_expanded"
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/header"/>

            <KeyAttribute
                android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation_expanded"
                app:framePosition="90"
                app:target="@id/header"/>


            <KeyAttribute
                android:elevation="@dimen/header_elevation_collapsed"
                app:framePosition="100"
                app:target="@id/header" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/header_expanded">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/guideline_expanded_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/header_condensed">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/guideline_expanded_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

If print the progress in the log it seems to jump from 0 to 1. I have tried changing the duration, or just changing the constraints for the header view to a different guideline but it doesn't seemt o affect the progress.

The only weird thing that I see in the logs is the fact that it cannot find the OnSwipe touchAnchorId view.

> W/MotionLayout: WARNING could not find view id com.pitchero.ph:id/view_pager

The layout using this MotionScence is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout android:id="@+id/container"
                                                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                      android:background="@color/activity_background"
                                                      app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene_team">

    <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/menu_header_elevation_expanded"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_expanded_state"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shape_diagonal_angle="@dimen/header_angle"
        app:shape_diagonal_direction="left"
        app:shape_diagonal_position="bottom">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/redE64"/>

    </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/title.white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:includeFontPadding="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                tools:text="Help Center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:tabBackground="@color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white_50_percent"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs_bar"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_expanded_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

I don't really understand why this is happening in this particular case. I suspect it's because it cannot find the ViewPager but I don't see why that would happen.

Also, I'm using the following version of the ConstraintLayout libs:

> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
>
> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:2.0.0-alpha3'

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented MotionLayout in a wrong way, first of all, you must not use Guideline to set animation, You can use **ViewGroup** containers or **View** for Animation.

Next thing, you must define all **ContraintSet** which are referencing another layout.
For ex.

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs_bar"/>
```

Here you are using **app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs_bar"** as a reference, so if you are animating That viewpager, you will need to add **ConstraintSet** for both of them, Then only you can get rid of that warning. :)